# Intuitionism and theoretical physics

Tags: logic, mathematical-physics, philosophy

In the book by Kleene "Introduction to Metamathematics" I have read that Poincare was intuitionist. Nevertheless, due to the fact that I am an undergraduate student in physics, I know that Poincare made significant contributions in physics theories.

Question: My confusion is about how could Poincare do theoretical physics while being intuitionist, because, as I understand it, intuitionism rejects completed infinite which is required to define real numbers, but on the other hand, theoretical physics is mainly about theorems that use real numbers.

Is it the case that he was both intuitionist and both formalist? How can that be? Maybe it is the case that most mathematicians are members of many schools of philosophy of foundations of the mathematics? But do then it makes sense to have such distinct schools at all? Did Poincare maybe do theoretical physics using constructive analysis (I don't think so because then I assume physicists would not understand him/his ideas)?

I would appreciate any ideas and comments!

Comment: I suggest that you read the mathematical and physical writings of Poincare. In the context that he worked in, what he accomplished is primary. Placing simplistic labels like "intuionist" on people does not help understanding.

Comment: Intuitionists don't (in general) have anything against completed infinites: you're mistaking with finitists. Intuitionism is mostly about constructive reasoning: to prove $A$ you can't assume $\neg A$ and prove that it's wrong; to prove that $\exists x, F(x)$ you have to actually exhibit such an $x$; etc.

Comment: @Max Kleene p.48: "The non-intuitionistic mathematics which culminated in the theories of Weierstrass, Dedekind and Cantor, and the intuitionistic mathematics of Brouwer, differ essentially in their view of the infinite. In the former, the infinite is treated as actual or completed or extended or existential.  In the latter, the infinite is treated only as potential or becoming or constructive."  I assume that it means (at least by Kleene's interpretation) that intuitionism rejects completed infinity.

Comment: Well this is Brouwer's intuitionism which is a bit "weird" : it can prove results that classical mathematics can't. "Strict" intuitionism is only the rejection of the use of the law of excluded middle : infinities may very well exist

Comment: [Henri Poincaré (1854-1912)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/poincare/) influenced [Intuitionism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/) (developed by [LEJ Brouwer (1881-1966)](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/brouwer/)) and [Predicativism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics/#Pre). He did not used [Constructive analysis](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/#VariConsMath) (developed from 1950s). The reference to *intuition* by HP was more to the Kantian sense of the concept.

Comment: Thus, intuition can base math on geometry, and the *continuum* of the real line can be "reduced" to the geometric line.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you as always

Comment: See also [What does Poincaré mean for intuition of pure number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1564456/what-does-poincar%c3%a9-mean-for-intuition-of-pure-number)